# How to remove and block "Visual Studio 2022 Fluent UI Refresh"

Tags: windows-10, visual-studio-2022

I'm running windows 10, and I don't like the changes that are in the "fluent UI refresh" for visual studio 2022, and want to go back to how they used to be.  I don't know what has caused this.  The thing I want to undo looks like this: [image]

The thing I had before, and want to go back to looks like this: [image]

How do I remove and permanently block this change?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the theme isn't part of Windows or any Windows component – it's part of the program itself. Probably the majority of UI components used by Visual Studio's main UI (tabs, toolbars, buttons, etc.) is either tailor-made for VS or has its UI style defined by VS, so its appearance will change if a VS update is released that changes the way those components are implemented, regardless of anything Windows does. Generally this is not something you can configure or revert in any way (except by downgrading the entire program to a previous version). The same also applies to all major web browsers, as well as every single app built on Electron (such as Discord or VSCode).

Comment: It's honestly not a part of visual studio. Both images are from visual studio enterprise 2022, version 17.8.0 Preview 4.0.  In other words, same exact version of VS2022, different computer.

Comment: VS has themes @gattsbr They're kinda limited, but there is theming in VS. Windows has some basic theming in the Themes section of Settings. But this mostly impacts the colors and highlights of applications, not the sizes and shapes of UI elements, or this hash pattern in VS.

Comment: [I don't believe this is a theme that can be disabled.  I suspect Microsoft and Google has updated, Visual Studio and Chrome, to have rounded corners on supported operating systems.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/desktop/modernize/apply-rounded-corners) In fact I know that is exactly what has happen due to [this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/visual-studio-ui-refresh/) blog article on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been nice if they would have listed this in whats new or something. I found an option to disable these changes.  Its still really odd that I have the same version of vs2022 on two machines one which has this change, and the other does not.  I'm still presuming this comes though windows update on a system level.
[image]

Comment: Visual Studio is never updated through Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound Visual Studio might not be, but it does use dll files from the system, which can be, and are updated though windows update, does it not?  Otherwise, what other explanation can be offered for having these changes on one system, but yet not available on another, when VS is the same version on both systems?